# js replace function not working within Snowflake UDF (but works fine in js previewer)

Tags: user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying create a Snowflake UDF to remove all non-numerics from a number string, like this:

```
create or replace function fnValidAusMobile(STRIN string)
  returns string
  language javascript
  strict
  as
  '
  var strIn = STRIN.replace(/\D/g,"") 
  return strIn
  '
  ;
```

However, when I test it, I can see the regex is not working, because the below returns this: '+61 401 111-111'

```
SELECT fnValidAusMobile('+61 401 111-111')
```

Strangely, when I use a js previewer, the regex works fine, so I'm baffled.

Any clues? Are there different rules / syntax for regex when used within a Snowflake UDF?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Could you write the regexp with double slashes?

```
create or replace function fnValidAusMobile(STRIN string)
  returns string
  language javascript
  strict
  as
  '
  var strIn = STRIN.replace(/\\D/g,"") 
  return strIn
  '
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked too! Cheers.

Comment: Two different solutions for the same problem, cool :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about escaping. If you change the `'` (single quote) to '$$' (double dollar sign) it should work fine.

```
create or replace function fnValidAusMobile(STRIN string)
  returns string
  language javascript
  strict
  as
  $$
  var strIn = STRIN.replace(/\D/g,"") 
  return strIn
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks, the $$ did the trick - much appreciated!

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking this method is simplest, given the $$ would work for everything within them, as opposed to need to double slash each regex?

Comment: I think so, yes.